# Execute script after deployment - MSDeploy

Tags: .net, deployment, tfs, msdeploy

Is there a way to trigger a custom script (or open a windows app) after a user imports the deployment package using IIS and completes the installation?

Any help?

Comment: Built package using TeamBuild. Deploying using IIS 7.0

Answer (score 13):

Try help for msdeploy.exe.

msdeploy.exe -help -postSync

or
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee619740(WS.10).aspx

> ```
> msdeploy -verb:sync -source:contentPath="C:\Test1"
>     -dest:contentPath="C:\Test2" -preSync:runcommand="Appcmd stop sites
>     MyWebSite" -postSync:runcommand="Appcmd start sites MyWebSite"
>
> msdeploy -verb:sync -source:contentPath="C:\Test1"
>     -dest:contentPath="C:\Test2" -preSync:runcommand="c:\MyBatchFile.bat"
>
> msdeploy -verb:sync -source:contentPath="C:\Test1"
>     -dest:contentPath="C:\Test2" -postSync:runcommand="c:\MyBatchFile.bat"
> ```

Comment: Got into a little bit of trouble with preSync and postSync commands. In short postSync did not worked if the order  was like: -presync... -source...-dest... -postSync...         They should be: preSync, postSync, source, dest  !