# Post deployment task for WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, msdeploy

Is it possible to run a post-deployment task (lets say a piece of code) immediately after the WCF service is deployed on IIS? I am using Visual Studio publish method to deploy the service.

Thanks

Comment: The `msdeploy` tool seems to have this option, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4746317/626761 ... would that help?